Is there a way to get the value of a player's selected inventory slot in Minecraft?
I am creating an ADDON in Minecraft bedrock version.
I want to get the value of the slot that the player has selected.
I know how to get the player's container from this article and how to scan the player's inventory.
But it did not describe how to get the slot that the player has selected.
("selected" in this case is the item in the player's hand)
If you are familiar with addon creation, please help me if you can.
Thank you.
import { world, Player, EntityInventoryComponent } from "@minecraft/server";

world.getPlayers().forEach((player) => {
  let inventory = player.getComponent("inventory") as EntityInventoryComponent;
}

